# How to find the closed form for this polynomial generating function with 2 variables

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form

I have the following generating function:

$ (x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^m)^k $

I want to find the coefficient of $x^n$ ($ n \geq k,m $)

I tried to think of it from a combinatorial perspective but couldn't get anywhere.

How do I go about it? Any ideas would be appreciated..

EDIT: As Macavity has pointed out, that is indeed what I'm trying to find.

The recurrence I came up with is:

$$ f(n,k) = \sum_{i=1}^m f(n-i, k-1) $$
where $ f(n,k) = 0 \space if \space n \leq 0 $ or $k \leq 0$

$and \space f(n,1) = 1 \space if n \in [1,m]$

Comment: Partition of $n$ into $k$ positive numbers not exceeding $m$?

Comment: @Macavity Yes. I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series.

> We obtain for $n,k\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^n]}&\color{blue}{(x+x^2+\cdots+x^m)^k}\\
> &=[x^n]x^k(1+x+\cdots+x^{m-1})^k\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{n-k}]\left(\frac{1-x^m}{1-x}\right)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^{n-k}]\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}(-1)^lx^{ml}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-k}{j}(-x)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^{\min\{\lfloor k/m \rfloor, \lfloor (n-k)/m \rfloor\}}\binom{k}{l}(-1)^l[x^{n-k-ml}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{k+j-1}{j}x^j\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{l=0}^{\min\{\lfloor k/m \rfloor, \lfloor (n-k)/m \rfloor\}}(-1)^l\binom{k}{l}\binom{n-ml-1}{k-1}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $x^k$.
- In (2) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
  and we apply the rule $$[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$$
- In (3) we apply the binomial theorem and use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, apply the rule as in (2) and restrict the upper limit of the outer series since the expoent of $x^{n-k-ml}$ is non-negative. We also use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
    \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q
    \end{align*}
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-k-ml}$.

Comment: @Rushil: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful! :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the summation as well?

Comment: @Rushil: I don't see a proper way to simplify the expression.